# software development - progress tracker

Tags: open-source, kanban

we are currently working with kanban boards. i am interested in the following numbers:

- how long does a task take until it is live
- how long does a task spend in each lane (dev,qa,staging...)

so speaking in abstract terms "how long does a card spend in each lane", where lane could be anything that is work related and takes resources.

we already have jira. are there any (very lightweight) tools that can handle this via website/app etc. and are not jira based? it should be very easy to handle.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the founders over at ScrumDo, and we can do exactly these sorts of stats with a very flexible report profile feature.

This feature lets you define a workflow (ie. development, testing) and then get statistics based on that.

From there there are two classes of reports that will give you what you want.  Our lead time histogram lets you slice and dice the data for the entire workflow, or just parts of it.  So you could, for instance, see how long cards takes to go from Development to Qa, but skip any deployment steps you have.

[image: Lead Time Histogram]
<sub>(source: [scrumdo.com](http://help.scrumdo.com/help/kanban/images/leadtime1.png))</sub>

Then there are three kinds of aging reports which would also help fulfill your requirements.  These reports help you understand how long cards sit in a given state.

Aging Histogram:
[image: Aging Histogram]
<sub>(source: [scrumdo.com](http://help.scrumdo.com/help/kanban/images/aging-histogram.png))</sub>

Aging breakdown:
[image: Aging Breakdown]
<sub>(source: [scrumdo.com](http://help.scrumdo.com/help/kanban/images/aging-breakdown.png))</sub>

Relative time spent:
[image: Relative Time]
<sub>(source: [scrumdo.com](http://help.scrumdo.com/help/kanban/images/aging-relative.png))</sub>

You can find full info or sign up here: http://www.scrumdo.com/

Here's a couple help articles showing off some of the reports we have: http://help.scrumdo.com/help/kanban/report-aging.html
http://help.scrumdo.com/help/kanban/report-lead.html

Comment: hi marc, thanks for your answer. i will check your tool out.